Old sci-fi movie with a chrome spaceship and aliens disguised as people eating organs under a black cloak
There was a movie I caught the end quarter of in a hotel room a couple years ago.
There were aliens (I guess) disguised as people amongst people who would 'appear' or transport (?) onto Earth, use a black cloak or something to absorb a human or their organs?  The spaceship was all chrome. There was a morality discussion on the spaceship before panning to one of the disguised people teleporting (fading out of the ship and onto Earth) to absorb a person.
It was in color but you could definitely tell it was an old one, definitely made before the 2000's, maybe the 80s?  I can still see the scene in my head but when looking online, I can't seem to find anything.

How that black cloak looked like? Was it ordinary cloak or some kind of cover? Was spaceship plate-like or had a long body? Were there any alien women? What was the ending?

This might be Life Force (1985). Churchill, the combined British and American space shuttle under the leadership of Colonel Tom Carlsen, discovers a 150-mile-long spaceship hiding in Halley's Comet's coma. A small team is dispatched to investigate the seemingly organic spaceship. Inside, they find hundreds of withered bat-like creatures. They were absorbing life force from Humans and leaving them as zombies.
